# Design Patterns: an overwork or still worth? (.NET 3.5/4.x)

Tags: .net, design-patterns

While working on .NET Framework 3.5/4.x (MVVM, Caliburn, MEF etc.) I have always been asking this question to myself, "More implementation of design patterns (GoF) needed?" and "As an experienced software engineer, should my sourcecode look like sourcecode with many design patterns?" Or "Are Design Patterns just an overwork, without much output?".

What is the best programming practice as a Senior Software Engineer, I mean should we do programming in MVVM without giving too much thought on "which Design Patterns could we use for our programming model"? Or "Should we spend a lot of time in the beginning, thinking on the programming model and identifying some design patterns that we can use and then writing the code?"

I dont know, if some design pattern from GoF still worth implementation. In summary, please give an expert advice for best programming practice for an experience software engineer (say 5 years of experience).

Answer (score 3):

Here's my $0.02:

The best programming practise is to solve the problem in the most efficient, simple, elegant and maintainable way you can. If a design pattern helps achieve one, or more, of these goals then use it.

Obviously, in reality there are trade-offs and these traits may have to be sacrificed to a lesser or greater extent. But, IMHO, that's the skill of an 'experienced' developer. Often a particular pattern might need to be modified beyond superficial recognition to meet your needs. However, a well-designed solution would truly be greater than the sum of its parts.

I think it's dangerous to try and fit solutions to patterns. Use patterns to inspire, communicate and as suggestions on best practise, but don't become a pattern snob or pattern slave.

Handrails, not handcuffs.